# scrapy data not encoded correctly in python

Tags: django, scrapy

I'm using scrapy for web crawling using python. While scraping I have some characters which are not encoded correctly like '\xa0','\x0259'. Any help how can I handle them in python?

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735836/scrapy-spider-dealing-with-pages-that-have-incorrectly-defined-character-encodi ?

Comment: you need to provide more context - do you have some code? Scrapy provides an API that allows you to deal with unicode, but here you show us some characters and I have no idea where they came from, what the correct character encoding is, or what you want to do with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unicode string type (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings) by prepending all instances of characters like these with `u`. For example `u'\xa0'` and `u'\x0259'`. The unicode-strings python docs also provide some other methods for encoding and decoding these strings and characters.